# Creating site column without using features

Tags: visual-studio, feature, site-column

I am trying to create a site column in VS2010 without using features. Is this possible? If yes, please let me know where I can start looking.

I don't want to use feature because feature comes with its own maintainability headache which I want to avoid as much as possible. I want to be able to individually install/update/delete each site column that I create in any given environment.

Comment: Another way is to use SharePoint APIs and do it using code.

Comment: Ashish, could you suggest a web-site or a textbook that can help me go down this path? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to avoid using declarative xml to create the column, you can write C# code to create the column. But to deploy to your site through a wsp, it will still need to be packaged in a feature.

You could write a console application that runs on the server and executes the code to create the column. However, this seems like more of a maintainability headache than creating a feature.

Either way, the code would look something like this:

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("url-of-your-site"))
{
  using(SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
  {
    web.Fields.Add("ColumnName", SPFieldType.Text, true);
  }
}
```

You could also create a Powershell script to add the column. Something like:

```
$site = Get-SPSite "your-site-url"
$web = $site.RootWeb 
$column = '<Field Name=...' +
                 'ID=...' +
                  etc. +
          '></Field>'
$web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($column)
```

But, really features aren't that bad once you accept that feature activation is the way to programmatically add elements to a SharePoint site.

Comment: Laurie, thank you for your answer. This is very helpful. I think I will give the console app a try. The reason I am not very happy about features is because I cannot delete one site column or content type from a given featuer - hence, as an end user I dont have much control over my own artifacts. The same issue will arise during upgrades for me as a developer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create columns in three ways:

- [By using the SharePoint 
  user interface](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/create-a-site-column-HA010157769.aspx)
- By using the SharePoint object model
- By deploying a Feature that installs the
  column based on an XML definition
  file

Comment: I have created the columns using both the UI and Features. But since both these approaches are kind of rigid per maintainability, I would like to try the Object Model. To that end, I have not found a definitive guide that can help me jump start this project.